# How to get in fourth gear

Tags: automatic-transmission, gears

I have 2007 automatic Scion tC that I just bought and I was wondering how do I put it in 4th gear or (sport)?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you only have 4 (4th being over drive) and no sport mode. Here is a link to the [Quick Reference PDF file download](http://www.scion.com/assets/pdf/quickReference/2007_Scion_tC_ReferenceGuide.pdf), though it really doesn't say a whole lot. It just shows the operation of the transmission lever. Should just be able to put it in **D**rive and go.

Comment: So (D)rive is my 4th gear?

Comment: Yes it is. Put the selector in **D** and you should be golden. If it is not going into over drive while your selector is in this position, you may have a transmission issue.

Comment: @Paulster2 Please turn your comment into an answer

Comment: @Paulster2  Can you turn your comment into an answer?   :)

Comment: @DucatiKiller - Thanks for the reminder ... I missed it somehow when Zaid posted on the 19th.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you only have 4 (4th being over drive) and no sport mode. Here is a link to the [Quick Reference PDF file download](http://www.scion.com/assets/pdf/quickReference/2007_Scion_tC_ReferenceGuide.pdf), though it really doesn't say a whole lot. It just shows the operation of the transmission lever. Should just be able to put it in Drive and go.

> So (D)rive is my 4th gear?

Yes it is. Put the selector in **D** and you should be golden. If it is not going into over drive while your selector is in this position, you may have a transmission issue.

Comment: BAM  94% yet?  lol